# jQuery $('html, body').not()

Tags: jquery, click

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/m2eqS/1/) - I want alert to happen when you click anywhere but not on the div.

When I click on div, alerts shows too.

***JS***

```
$("html, body").not('.entry-content').click(function() {            
    alert('d');                        
}); ​
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="entry-content"> kkkk </div>​
```

Comment: It doesn't work because the `.not('.entry-content')` doesn't stop the event from bubbling to the body and html nodes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the event argument to see what target was clicked and return false

```
$("html, body").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('entry-content')) {
        return false;
    }
    alert('d');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/keyZw/

You are using the .not() filter.. but it's still part of your html/body.. so you need to handle it inside the click function.  Also you are just binding the click event..

So

```
 // find html,body - not ones with class=entry-content - bind click
 $("html, body").not('.entry-content')
```

So that doesn't prevent the alert as your div is still inside the body

As mentioned.. you only need to bind to the body really

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('entry-content')) {
        return false;
    }
    alert('d');
});​
```

Comment: in your function you have an `e` parameter, but in the body you're using `event` ;-)

Comment: Also, don't do `html, body` (there's no reason to and it creates two click events, just do `$('body').on('click')`

Comment: Same remark as to Zoltan's answer : I would remove either html or body, as we have often two alerts...

Comment: when you use 'body' only, alert will not appear when you click for example below div. thats why I used both.

Comment: @jaimpact then use `html` only. if you use both and click on the right of the div, you'll have two alerts !

Comment: acidentally I've made click example to show the problem. Main work is made on hover and mousewheel effect. Will it work? :) Im asking while your still here. Im checking it.

Comment: Sorry about that, your solution is ok. But now i need to use it that way: when mousewheel event happens - do something everywhere, but not when div class=a is hovered. i thinkg both mousewheel and hover dont have e.target. Sorry, I could describe it better, I didnt thought that soultions may be different.

Comment: Does the OP wants a sub element to trigger the event ? If not see my [down voted without any explanation answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12958888/305189)

Comment: @jaimpact yes they have the event argument also.. check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dbsmf/

Answer (score 7):

```
$("html *").click(function(e) {
    if ( e.target.className.indexOf("entry-content") < 0 ) {
        alert('d');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m2eqS/7/)

---

The original code doesn't work because the `.not()` applies to the selectors in front of it - `html` and `body`. Neither of them has the class of `entry-content`, so the event fires

Comment: yep Rajat Singhal, I just wanted to ask this.

Comment: @archer/Rajatsinghal More than one class wasn't part of the question. Neither was why isn't the code working.

Comment: Just pointing out a flaw with this answer - the answer using `hasClass()` does not have this flaw.  Think ahead.  Also, the question doesn't specify either way, so it's worth mentioning.

Comment: You'll hate me for this, but I'm a pedant.  What if there are elements using the class name "entry-contents", or "wentry-content" - sorry, but `hasClass()` is the correct way to go.  You'd have to do `indexOf(" entry-content ")`, and check startsWith and endsWith as well to do it your way.  Far easier to use the jQuery method.

Comment: @Archer you're absolutely right - if there was a class of `wentry-content` then it will fail.. But what are the chances, that you as a web developer will write such vague and indistinct class names? :) BTW I like how you think WAY ahead. Thumbs up for that.

Comment: Thanks for taking it in your stride and not calling me a pain in the butt :p  I do think way ahead, for sure.  It's what 30 years coding does to you!  But you're right, it's ridiculously unlikely, and if you make such vague class names then you sort of deserve it :D

Comment: What happens if there are elements inside ? Most likely the OP would like them not to fire the event, wouldn't he ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also stop propagation on the element clicked

```
$("body").click(function() {
    alert();
});

$(".entry-content").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Works also by clicking on a sub element

```
<div class="entry-content">Element
  <span>Sub element</span>
</div>​
```

Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2eqS/8/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding the click event to the HTML and BODY tags.  So, first off you're going to get 2 alerts when you click in the body area. Also, because of the way events propagate up, clicking on the DIV in question will propagate the click event up to body and html as well.  So, you need to do a check inside the click handler to determine whether or not you want to show the alert message.

I modified your jsfiddle below to only include HTML in your selector, and to check for the `entry-content` class within the handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/m2eqS/6/

```
$("html").click(function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass("entry-content")){
      alert('TEST');
   }                        
}); ​
```

The difference between binding to HTML and to BODY is that if you want to be able to click anywhere on the page, below where the content/body ends, you should use HTML.  Otherwise use BODY.