# two onClick() events happening simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

What I am expecting from my code is this:
When clicking a button, a menu of options appears at the pointer position. Any following click, whether on a menu item or elsewhere in the browser, should close the menu. Clicking on a menu item closes the menu, but not clicking anywhere else. When I uncomment `$(document.body).one('click', function() {menu.remove()}` the menu never appears in the first place, and I suspect that I somehow have it arranged so that the click to bring up the menu actually closes the menu as well. Here is the code:

```
render : function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            var that = this;
            if (this.model.attributes.memberType != 'OWNER') {

                this.$('.memberTypeSelector').button({
                    icons : {
                        secondary : "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    }
                }).click(function(event) {
                    that.showPermissions(that.model, event, that);
                });
            ...
},

showPermissions : function(member, event, view) {
            var levels = ['ADMIN', 'CONTRIBUTOR', 'VIEWER'];
            var menu = $('<ul>');
            $.each(levels, function() {
                if(member.attributes.memberType !== this) {
                    var item = $('<li>').appendTo(menu);
                    $('<a>').attr('href', '#').text(this).appendTo(item).click(function() {
                        menu.remove();
                        view.changePermission(member, this.text, view);
                    });
                }
            });
            menu.menu().css({
                position : 'absolute',
                left : event.clientX,
                top : event.clientY
            });
            $(document.body).append(menu);
            /*$(document.body).one('click', function() {
                menu.remove();
            });*/
        }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you delay binding to the document by 10ms, that should be enough time for the event to propagate to the body so that it doesn't immediately close the menu, then the next click on the menu will result in the body click handler triggering.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(document.body).one('click', function() {menu.remove();});
},10)
```

you can't use stop propagation or anything similar because that would also stop the 2nd click on the menu.

Answer (score 0):

While delaying the second event binding will probably work 99.999% of the time, I can't help but feel that nagging 'what if' for the one time that something lags and it doesn't work.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958734/jquery-html-body-not) provides a more satisfactory (at least to me) solution