# Hide div class when click outside

Tags: javascript

```js
function nav_category_show() {
    var x = document.getElementById("nav_dropdown_items");
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
    } 

    else { 
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    }   
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    
    
<span onclick="nav_category_show()">click here<i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>

<div id="nav_dropdown_items" class="w3-animate-zoom w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
   <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
            
</div>
```

I want to hide this #nav_dropdown_items when click on outside of the div.How should I do it? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery $('html, body').not()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958734/jquery-html-body-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding class in the `nav_category_show` function stop the event propagation using `event.stopPropagation`.

Add another event to the `body` and in that remove the class from `nav_category_show`

```js
function nav_category_show(e) {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav_dropdown_items");
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else {
    x.className = x.className.replace("w3-show", "");
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("nav_dropdown_items").classList.remove('w3-show');

})
```

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<span onclick="nav_category_show(event)">click here<i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>

<div id="nav_dropdown_items" class="w3-animate-zoom w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already referencing jquery, you can use it to easily hide / show the div of choice:

```
var target = $("#nav_dropdown_items");
if(target.hasClass("w3-show")) {
  target.hide();  // hides it
  target.removeClass("w3-show");
}
else {
  target.show();  //shows it
  target.addClass("w3-show");
}
```

Comment: you don't need to write `$(target)`, the target variable is already a jQuery object, so you don't need to call jQuery more times. Just write `target.hasClass('foo')` etc